# ABAP-DDS using BC connector

Tags: abap, bc

We need to upgrade Milemaker server from WIN2003 to WIN2008. 
Currently we are using com4abap and we need to use DDS using BC connector to connect to Milemaker.

DDS will be purchased and configured. Once done RFC destination from SAP will be updated to point to new server. 
But apart from that what are the changes required in ABAP programs?

For ex. I have a program to calculate freight cost which has following steps:

1. COM session is created (by passing the RFC destination in SM59).
2. Get_SAP_DISTANCE FM is called by passing origin and destination to get the mileage (target destination will be as obtained in first step).
3. COM session closed.

Once it is changed to DDS, what is the change/modification needed in this ABAP program?
Any pointers will help a lot.

Comment: SO if for questions that have an issue, you do no yet have an issue to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following notes should answer your questions:

https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/422696

https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/597796

In general it seems you get out-of-the-box services prepared for SAP BC which you execute by calling FM /SAPDDS/BAPI_GET_DISTANCE in your ABAP report with destination indicating your SAP BC server. Under note 422696 you have can find attached PDF file *SAP_BC_DDS_Service.pdf* which should explain everything.

Comment: Thanks. I would need to know Can we connect from SAP to Milemaker via BC without DDS? Is DDS compulsory for communication between SAp and Milemaker using BC? Request you inputs. Thanks